# Delete item from Strings.xml by tapping on ListView - Android c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, arrays, listview, xamarin

I have a ListView which retrieves and displays data from Strings.xml String Array.
I was wondering how would I Delete a string from the Strings.xml array if I tap on the String in ListView.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    ListView notesList;
    String[] notesArray;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        ActionBar.Hide();

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        notesArray = Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.testStrings);

        notesList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvNotes);



        //Load ListView Data
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1, notesArray);

        notesList.Adapter = adapter;

    }
}
```

}

And Strings.xml:

[image: Strings.xml]

Comment: You can't modify resources at runtime.

Comment: So how am I supposed to make the data editable and to modify the file and save it after?

Comment: You'd have to use some other way to store your data; e.g., a file, a database, etc. That's not to say that you couldn't load your array from resources initially; you'd just have to save the modified version another way.

Comment: Or can i delete it from the String inside MainActivity and save that to Strings.xml file?